# Istio DestinationRule not being applied

Tags: istio

Given a pod making an outbound connection to an external service, where the external service has multiple endpoints for resiliency, I'm trying to leverage Istio to do load balancing and failover across those multiple endpoints.

I have the load balancing working - but I can't get the `DestinationRule` to take affect.

## K8s service

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wcf-service
  namespace: wcf-proxy
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
```

## Virtual Service

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: wcf-virtual-service
  namespace: wcf-proxy
spec:
  hosts:
  - wcf-service
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: 95af-2a02-etc.ngrok-free.app
        port:
          number: 80
      headers:
        request:
          set:
            Host: 95af-2a02-etc.ngrok-free.app
      weight: 50
    - destination:
        host: ff25-2a02-etc.ngrok-free.app
        port:
          number: 80
      headers:
        request:
          set:
            Host: ff25-2a02-etc.ngrok-free.app
      weight: 50
```

- Note that I had to do the host header thing, otherwise NGrok requests it because it has a different host header.
- I've also tested giving one endpoint the majority of the weight, just to check the virtual service is being picked up - and this does work.

## ServiceEntry

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: wcf-service
  namespace: wcf-proxy
spec:
  hosts:
  - 95af-2a02-etc.ngrok-free.app
  - ff25-2a02-etc.ngrok-free.app
  exportTo:
  - "*"
  ports:
  - number: 80
    name: http
    protocol: HTTP
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  resolution: DNS
```

## Destination Rule

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: wcf-destination-rule
  namespace: wcf-proxy
spec:
  host: wcf-service
  trafficPolicy:
    outlierDetection:
      consecutiveGatewayErrors: 2
      consecutive5xxErrors: 2
      interval: 10s
      baseEjectionTime: 2m
      maxEjectionPercent: 100
```

I'm spinning up a separate pod...

```bash
kubectl run my-shell -n blah --rm -i --tty --image curlimages/curl:latest -- sh
```

- That's in a different namespace, but I've tested from the same one too
- Both namespaces have istio injection enabled

And running this inside the pod...

```bash
curl -v wcf-service.wcf-proxy.svc.cluster.local
```

To test, I just have two nginx instances running locally in Docker that I'm exposing through ngrok. I then stop one of them, expecting it to stop routing to that one after a few failures, but it doesn't...

[image]

So everything seems to be working except for the DestinationRule.

I've also tried the DestinationRule host matching the external hostnames instead...

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: wcf-destination-rule
  namespace: wcf-proxy
spec:
  host: 95af-2a02-c7c-b406-2b00-25cc-b273-a06d-7f98.ngrok-free.app
  trafficPolicy:
    outlierDetection:
      consecutiveGatewayErrors: 2
      consecutive5xxErrors: 2
      interval: 10s
      baseEjectionTime: 2m
      maxEjectionPercent: 100
```

*(and a corresponding one for the other endpoint)*

But that didn't work either.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

I've ran `istioctl proxy-config route my-shell.blah -o json` to see if the JSON output mentions the `outlierDetection`, but it doesn't.